# Force Full Path in the Connection String of Linq DataContext

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, linq, substitution

I'm using System.Data.Linq.DataContext file for accessing a mdf Database

I want to use the Database from the project directory and not the one created by the debugger in the Debug directory.

The problem is when I edit the Connection String and choose the path for AttachDBFilename,
VS2008 automaticly substitutes my project directory with "|DataDirectory|"

How do I get arround this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your application "app.config" file
Go to the connectionStrings and change the connectionString to the path of your DB.

At the DataContext file properties, set the "Application Settings" = True
Then choose the Connection by it's name and that it.

Answer (score 0):

already you can write like this:
SampledbDataContext sdc = new SampledbDataContext(Server.MapPath("~/Sampledb.mdf"));
or in design.cs file
public SampledbDataContext() : 
base(global::"[write cnn string Here !]", mappingSource)
{
        OnCreated();
}